# How to solve adfContext leak on oracle-bi or enable adfContext finest logging?

Tags: weblogic, oracle-adf, oracle-bi

In our Weblogic server log we get "ADFContext Leak" error and our app freezes. How to enable ADFContext finest logging on oralce BI? Or how to solve this ADFContext leak?

Comment: [English text formatting tutorial](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370)

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer to your first question: Enable ADFContext finest logging on Oracle BI?

Log on to Enterprise Manager console.

Expand:
Target Navigation > WebLogic Domain > Server Cluster

Right Click:
Server from the Server Cluster

Click:
Logs > Log Configuration

Follow the screenshot for setting the desired logging level for the desired logger.

[image: Log Configuration using Oracle Enterprise Manager 12c]